# Notary for translated documents UK standard visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying for a standard visitor visa application for a family member. They have a property in India and the original title deed is in the regional language, They have got it translated into English by an independent translator in their town, and have a confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document but the translator mentioned that you might have to get it notarized.
my question is do we need to notarize these documents? Does anyone here have experience with this? been trying to search about this nothing comes up. except this:

[image]

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: I would go with what the visa issuer requires, not what the translator says. The link you posted say this: *9. Documents you should not use as evidence ... notarial certificates.*

Comment: @WeatherVane: Surely that means notarial certificates of the applicant's sincere intention to return home? That is, I go to a notary and solemnly swear before them that I intend to return home? The OP is asking a different question, I think.

Comment: @TonyK it isn't specific. Visa application information is usually quite good at saying what you need to provide, and here it goes to lengths to say what you don't need. Perhaps the translator has experience of providing certified translations for other English-speaking countries that do require a notary to confirm.